# How to solve assembly bindings issues with vstest on azure pipeline

Tags: .net, microsoft-graph-api, azure-pipelines, mstest, vstest

I am trying to run some mstest tests in an Azure release pipeline, on an on-premise agent, through the [Visual Studio Test task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/vstest?view=azure-devops).
The test project target framework is .net 4.8.

It seems I have some binding redirects issues, but I am unable to solve them.

Run locally on a developer workstation, the tests work.
In the Azure pipeline, they fail with the following error (partially translated from french):

```
Test method _TestAuto.OrderTest.SomeTest threw exception: 
System.IO.FileLoadException: Unable to load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
Arborescence des appels de procédure :
    à System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
    à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ValueTaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
    à Microsoft.Graph.Serializer.DeserializeObject[T](Stream stream)
    à Microsoft.Graph.ResponseHandler.<HandleResponse>d__2`1.MoveNext()
--- Fin de la trace de la pile à partir de l'emplacement précédent au niveau duquel l'exception a été levée ---
    à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    à Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.<SendAsync>d__34`1.MoveNext()
--- Fin de la trace de la pile à partir de l'emplacement précédent au niveau duquel l'exception a été levée ---
    à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    à Microsoft.Graph.UserMessagesCollectionRequest.<GetAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- Fin de la trace de la pile à partir de l'emplacement précédent au niveau duquel l'exception a été levée ---
    à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    à _TestAuto.MailHelper.<FindEmailAsync>d__9.MoveNext() in D:\a\1\s\Tests\_TestAuto\MailHelper.cs:line 161
```

The test uses Microsoft.Graph 4.2.0 NuGet package, and it fails with the error shown above, when calling `Microsoft.Graph.UserMessagesCollectionRequest.GetAsync` as shown in the stack trace above.

When exploring its dependencies, we can see it depends on Microsoft.Graph.Core 2.0.2, depending on:

- Azure.Core 1.17.0 which depends on System.Memory 4.5.4 which depends on **System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe 4.5.3**
- System.Text.Json 5.0.2 which depends on **System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe 5.0.0**
  (There are also many other version mismatches on and through many other dependencies.)

On the on-premise agent, in the test binaries folder, I can find System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe 5.0.0.

So this looks like a classical case requiring binding redirects. But enabling binding auto-generation in the test csproj does not change anything.

```xml
<AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
<GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
```

Explicitly adding binding redirects in the test config file for that assembly does not solve the issue either, the error message stay the same.

```xml
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

I have checked the GAC of my developer workstation, there is nothing there matching that assembly, so I guess that locally for some reason, some binding redirects are automagically handled somewhere because it works locally even without any of the above bindings redirects settings.

How can we solve this dependency hell in the case of an Azure pipeline?

The on premise agent does not have Visual Studio installed, I use the [Visual Studio Test Platform Installer task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/vstest-platform-tool-installer?view=azure-devops).
Its yaml is:

```
steps:
- task: VisualStudioTestPlatformInstaller@1
  displayName: 'Visual Studio Test Platform Installer'
  inputs:
    versionSelector: latestStable
```

The Visual Studio Test task yaml is:

```
steps:
- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: 'VsTest - testAssemblies'
  inputs:
    testAssemblyVer2: '**\*TestAuto*.dll'
    searchFolder: '$(test_temp)'
    vsTestVersion: toolsInstaller
    rerunFailedTests: true
```

And finally, the test binaries are built with a MSBuild task, with this yaml:

```
steps:
- task: MSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build Tests'
  inputs:
    solution: 'Tests\_TestAuto\_TestAuto.csproj'
    msbuildArchitecture: x64
    configuration: Release
```

Answer (score 0):

Following Nick Craver's [advice](https://nickcraver.com/blog/2020/02/11/binding-redirects/), I have solved this by migrating the test project to .Net Core.
For people forced to stay on .Net Framework, I have not found another solution. (I have not invested more time in seeking one anyway.)